# how to draw subgroup lattices? (e.g., for $C_2 × C_2$)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

In general how do you draw subgroup lattices? I missed the class we learned how to draw then and I was wondering if someone can help me learn how to do it? For example with $C_2 × C_2$.

Comment: do you mean the subgroup lattice?

Comment: yes i did mean that

Comment: are you asking how to draw the subgroup lattice with LaTeX, or instead how to compute subgroups? the "drawing" part is pretty trivial, if you're doing it by hand. just arrange the subgroups by inclusion. so I'm guessing what you're really asking is: how do you find subgroups?

Comment: Yes I am doing them by hand. I guess so

Comment: Figure out what the subgroups are, figure out which subgroups are in which other subgroups, then draw the corresponding points and lines.